# How can I change a Discord server's notification settings with a Discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on a bot for a Discord server which is only open at night. It will delete a users message during the day, but users still get a notification that a message was sent. How can I turn of server default notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change a server's notification settings by using [Guild.default_notifications](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.default_notifications). This is a kwarg of [.edit()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.edit).
Example:

```py
await ctx.guild.edit(default_notifications=what_you_want_to_change_here)
```